# changing style based on content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a html

```
<div class="common">
<p class="special">
    <p class="child">test1</p>
</p>
<p class="special">
    <p class="child">test2</p>
</p></div>
```

as you see i have two paragraphs with same style but different content, i want to change only and only the style of paragraph which content contains "test1", 
wrote something like this

```
$(".common").each(function () {
if ($(this).find('.special').find('.child').text() == "test1")
{
    $(this).find('.special').find('.child').css('background','red');
}});
```

but the style is applied to both paragraphs, is there any solution to solve this in javascript/jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is invalid - `p` element cannot contain another `p` element

```
<div class="common">
    <div class="special">
        <p class="child">test1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="special">
        <p class="child">test2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
$(".common .special .child").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == "test1") {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Rb5Gg/)

You code will find the first `.special .child` element`inside each`.common`and if its text matches the test case then it applies the styles to all`.special .child`elements within the`.common`

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter

```
$(".common > .special > .child").filter(function(){
   return $(this).text() == "test1"
}).css('background', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".common .child").each(function () {    
 if ($(this).text() == "test1"){$(this).css('background','red');}});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DR5Lk/2/)**